# Posting form data with file results in "The input was not valid" error

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using Postman to test a .Net Core 2.1 Web API.  I started with this and it worked -- I was able to send a file from Postman to my Web API.

**Web.API**

```
[HttpPost("uploads")]
public IActionResult FileUpload(IFormFile myfile)
{
   ...
   return Ok();
}
```

However, **I need to pass some additional form data along with the file**.  Based on other posts that I've seen, I tried the following:

```
[HttpPost("uploads")]
public IActionResult FileUpload(UploadFile data)
{
    ...
    return Ok();
}

public class UploadFile {
   public IFormFile myfile {get; set;}
   public bool forceOverwrite {get; set;}
}
```

Now posting from Postman results in "The input was not valid".  I've done some searching and can't seem to find anybody that has gotten something like this working.

**Update**

I also tried the following; however, the additional value always comes in false -- even when sent as true.

```
public IActionResult FileUpload(IFormFile myfile, bool forceOverwrite)
```

**Update 2**

[image]

[image]

Here is what I added in Postman, and also how it appears in Fiddler.  (P.S. You can ignore the fact that the route in the POST doesn't match the route listed in my code -- I chose to simplify things for the post in regards to naming.

Comment: The HTTP Request you are sending from Postman is not correctly formed to the signature of your new FileUpload(UploadFile data) so Web API cannot parse it correctly, you need to include your Postman HTTP Request in your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For binding FormData in .NET Core Web API, you will need to add `FromForm` attribute like below

```
    [HttpPost("uploads")]
    public IActionResult FileUpload([FromForm]UploadFile data)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had tried FromBody like I used to do with previous versions of Web API, but that didn't work.  Again, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
 public class UploadFile
    {

        public bool forceOverwrite { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    }
```

and in your controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(UploadFile upload)
        {
            var file = upload.File; // This is the IFormFile file
            var param = upload.forceOverwrite; // param
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                          await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            return Ok(new { count = 1, path = filePath,filename=upload.forceOverwrite });
        }
```

Here is the output from postman

[image]